# C++ whats the difference between these two codes to make an array of objects?

Tags: c++, object, pointers

I’m really confused about these two lines of codes. What’s the difference between them?

One is created on heap and the other on stack?

```cpp
classname *arrayofobjects[50];
```

and

```cpp
classname *arrayofobjects = new classname[50];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`classname* arrayofobjects[50];` declares a stack array of 50 elements, where each element is of type `classname*` (a pointer to `classname`). `classname* arrayofobjects = new classname[50];` heap-allocates an array of 50 of objects `classname`, constructs them with their default constructor, and sets `arrayofobjects` to a pointer to the first element of the array. (note that pointers to the first element essentially act as arrays)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is where the array (of 50 pointers) is allocated.  In generic C++ there are two typical locations:

a) automatic memory

b) dynamic memory

( There can be locations that are neither a nor b in embedded systems. )